# How does reversing a Linked List using recursion work?

Tags: c++, data-structures

I am looking for an explanation on how reversing a linked list using recursion works, the code is given below but I am not able to figure how it works.

```
ListNode* reverseListRecursive(ListNode* head)
{
    if (head == NULL || head->next == NULL)
        return head;
    ListNode *temp = reverseListRecursive(head->next);
    head->next->next = head;
    head->next = NULL;
    return temp;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code with a debugger? Or what kind of explanation are you looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A list of `nil` is it's own reverse.

A list of `head -> nil` is also it's own reverse.

A list of `head -> tail` has a reverse that is `reverse(tail)` followed by `head`. The first element of `tail` will be at the end of `reverse(tail)`, and `head->next` still points to that element after you `reverse(tail)`, so you can put `head` at the end by following `head->next->next`.